# ReactJs - NextJs Error - (No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http, cors, mern

Hi everyone I am creating a MERN stack application. When I'm trying to upload a video through a route to s3 from the frontend.
I am getting this error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

In nodejs I've set up cors correctly.

In the the frontend (nextjs) I am using this function to upload the video:

```
const appendVideo = (values) => {
  const message = 'Wait until the page is refreshed ! Video will be listed down below';
  dispatch(showNotification('info', message));
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', videofile);
  const url = `${apiUrl}/courses/upload/${videofile.name}`;
  axios.post(url, formData).then((res) => {
    onSubmit(values, res);
  });
};
```

Down below I am using this function to upload an image and it works fine.

```
const submitImage = () => {
  const message = 'Wait until the the image is uploaded';
  dispatch(showNotification('info', message));
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', imageFile);
  const url = `${apiUrl}/courses/upload/${imageFile.name}`;
  axios.post(url, formData).then(() => {
    setImageText(imageFile);
  });
};
```

I am using DigitalOcean and I have 2 subdomains (api.test.com and dashboard.test.com). The request is from dashboard.test.com.

I am using Nginx to map the ip address (12.123.1234:4002) to the subdomain

Answer (score 0):

You must config cors of S3 on AWS allow dashboard.test.com domain. See AWS document at here [AWS Document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html). This code bellow is example:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://dashboard.test.com</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: I don't think this is the case, I've set up correctly cors on s3, it works fine on localhost, only when I deploy it throws that error

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.test.com/courses/upload/test.mov' from origin 'https://dashboard.test.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Do you setup CORS on api.test.com allow dashboard.test.com?

Comment: yes i've done that, i've white listed dashboard.test.com

Comment: This is problem in server-side. You can config CORS from your code or web server(nginx , apache,httpd, ..). May be your config CORS is wrong.